How to estimate the error when approximating a definite integral with Taylor’s polynomial?
I want to approximate the integral $\int_{-1}^1\sin(x^2)\cos(k\pi x)\ dx$ with the Taylor’s polynomial of degree 2 centred at $x_0=0$. It is simply:
$\int_{-1}^1(x^2)(1-\frac{k^2\pi^2}{2}x^2)\ dx=\frac{1}{3}x^3-\frac{k^2\pi^2}{10}x^5|_{-1}^1=\frac{2}{3}-\frac{k^2\pi^2}{5}.$
Now, in addition to it, I want to estimate the error of this approximation as well. If integration is not involved, it can be done by using Lagrange’s remainder. For example, $\sin(x^2)=x^2-\frac{1}{6}\xi^4$, where $\xi\in(0,x)$.
I am thinking computing $\int_{-1}^1(x^2-\frac{1}{6}\xi_1^4)(1-\frac{k^2\pi^2}{2}x^2+\frac{k^4\pi^4}{24}\xi_2^4)\ dx$ and bound the result with $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(-1,1)$ but this approaching doesn’t seem rigorous enough for me (maybe it is even wrong). I can’t see how $\xi_1,\xi_2\in(-1,1)$.
Thanks for any answers in advance.
